# Error installing multi-rake in python (or pycld2) on Microsoft

Tags: python, c++builder

When I try to install pycld2 (pip install pycld2), I have the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsVZJ.png)

```
Installing collected packages: pycld2
  DEPRECATION: pycld2 is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for pycld2 ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pycld2 did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycld2
      copying pycld2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycld2
      running build_ext
      building 'pycld2._pycld2' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pycld2

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Then, if I install the "Microsoft C++ Build Tools", with the Visual Studio Installer--C++ Build Tools for Desktop
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yit0a.png)

and I have the next error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pycld2
  Building wheel for pycld2 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [39 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      The [wheel] section is deprecated. Use [bdist_wheel] instead.
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycld2
      copying pycld2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycld2
      running build_ext
      building 'pycld2._pycld2' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\bindings
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\internal
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\internal -IC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\public -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt /EHsc /TpC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\bindings\encodings.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\bindings\encodings.obj -w -O2 -m64 -fPIC
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9025 : invalidando '/W3' con '/w'
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9002 : se omite la opci¢n desconocida '-m64'
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9002 : se omite la opci¢n desconocida '-fPIC'
      encodings.cc
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\internal -IC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\public -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt /EHsc /TpC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\bindings\pycldmodule.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\bindings\pycldmodule.obj -w -O2 -m64 -fPIC
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9025 : invalidando '/W3' con '/w'
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9002 : se omite la opci¢n desconocida '-m64'
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9002 : se omite la opci¢n desconocida '-fPIC'
      pycldmodule.cc
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\internal -IC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\public -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt /EHsc /TpC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\internal/cld2_generated_cjk_compatible.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\internal/cld2_generated_cjk_compatible.obj -w -O2 -m64 -fPIC
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9025 : invalidando '/W3' con '/w'
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9002 : se omite la opci¢n desconocida '-m64'
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9002 : se omite la opci¢n desconocida '-fPIC'
      cld2_generated_cjk_compatible.cc
      C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\internal\cld2_generated_cjk_compatible.cc : fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo generado por el compilador: '': Invalid argument
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycld2
  Running setup.py clean for pycld2
Failed to build pycld2
Installing collected packages: pycld2
  Running setup.py install for pycld2 ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pycld2 did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [38 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycld2
      copying pycld2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycld2
      running build_ext
      building 'pycld2._pycld2' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\bindings
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\internal
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\internal -IC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\public -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt /EHsc /TpC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\bindings\encodings.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\bindings\encodings.obj -w -O2 -m64 -fPIC
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9025 : invalidando '/W3' con '/w'
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9002 : se omite la opci¢n desconocida '-m64'
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9002 : se omite la opci¢n desconocida '-fPIC'
      encodings.cc
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\internal -IC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\public -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt /EHsc /TpC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\bindings\pycldmodule.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\bindings\pycldmodule.obj -w -O2 -m64 -fPIC
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9025 : invalidando '/W3' con '/w'
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9002 : se omite la opci¢n desconocida '-m64'
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9002 : se omite la opci¢n desconocida '-fPIC'
      pycldmodule.cc
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\internal -IC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\public -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt /EHsc /TpC:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\internal/cld2_generated_cjk_compatible.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\internal/cld2_generated_cjk_compatible.obj -w -O2 -m64 -fPIC
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9025 : invalidando '/W3' con '/w'
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9002 : se omite la opci¢n desconocida '-m64'
      cl : L¡nea de comandos warning D9002 : se omite la opci¢n desconocida '-fPIC'
      cld2_generated_cjk_compatible.cc
      C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ulnf3ec2\pycld2_dbee1b48c2e2491bb1ff0570cfac0386\cld2\internal\cld2_generated_cjk_compatible.cc : fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo generado por el compilador: '': Invalid argument
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pycld2

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I tried to install that, to use --pre, to use pip install nameofrepositryingithub...and nothing works.